# How to call expect in @testing-library/react

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import user  from '@testing-library/user-event';
import FirebaseLogin from './AuthLogin';
import i18n from '../../../../i18nForTests';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';

test('shows error message when email is empty', async () => {
      i18n.changeLanguage('en');      
      const comp = render(<I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}><FirebaseLogin /></I18nextProvider>); 
      const emailInput = getEmail();
      await user.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /sign in/i }));

      await waitFor(() => {
        expect(getEmail()).toHaveErrorMessage('Email is required');
      });
  });

  function getEmail() {
    return screen.getByRole('textbox', {  name: /email address/i});
  }
```

When I run this test via `npm test`, it write the following error:

```
TypeError: expect(...).toHaveErrorMessage is not a function
```

Do you know, what is wrong wiht my settings or code?

Comment: I have found the solution.
To install this library:
```
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/jest-dom
```
and then to include it:
```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

Comment: it's better to explain what do you want to do with this test.
Also why did you write `getEmail` function?